# Add label inside a TextView on android

Tags: java, android, label, textview

Is it possible to add a `TextView` inside a `EditText`?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with label?

Comment: TextView is same as a Label in Java Swing

Comment: Sorry, i asked it wrong, I reformulated the question.

Comment: This still isn't clear - give an example of what you want to do. An EditText IS a TextView (in the sense of inheritance at least) assuming you mean in Android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082462/label-in-a-editbox-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you want a `TextView` label and an edit box `TextEdit`...

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
TextView label = new TextView(this);
EditText edit = new EditText(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
label.setText("My Label");
edit.setText ("My Edit");
ll.addView(label, layoutParams);
ll.addView(edit, layoutParams);
setContentView(ll);
```

You can find the API here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

You can also add those as xml files. There's a very simple tutorial (that you could easily adapt to this) here: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

Answer (score 7):

With your edit, I'm assuming what you're looking for is `EditText`'s `android:hint` attribute. This will add a slightly transparent caption inside the EditText which will disappear upon pressing it.