# Label in a editbox in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

My question is, how to put a label in a **editBox** in android ?

Like for example, i want to put "To:" in **editbox** of a contact picker which will not get deleted even if I press backspace on the onscreen keyboard.

I tried with **android:hint**, but it gets deleted when the editBox is focus or clicked.

I tried with image but it's not looking good.
So, I need a method by which i can implement this label thing.

See the visual diagram [image: required design]

Comment: it means you want "To :" along with the text you entered ????

Comment: @Preet - Yes, but "To:" should not be deleted.

Comment: you can simply combine TextView along with your EditText

Comment: if you want to display only hint then you can use hint property of EditText

Comment: i want to implement the label "To:" at the extreme left of textbox

Comment: see my comment matt... I hope that will answer your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText Label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741863/edittext-label)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I give you two ideas to do this :

If you only need this in a couple of places, you can use a FrameLayout / merge to have a TextView over your EditText. Then using a padding on the edit text, you can make it seem like the TextView is "inside" the EditText. :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="To : " />
</FrameLayout>
```

Else you can inplement your own version of EditText, by writing your own Class. Here's a basic example, you'd need to tweak it a little :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LabelledEditText extends EditText {

    public LabelledEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    }

    public LabelledEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        Rect size = new Rect();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(mLabel, 0, mLabel.length(), size);
        setPadding(mPaddingLeft + size.width(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom());
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawText(mLabel, mPaddingLeft + size.left, size.bottom + getPaddingTop(), textPaint);
    }


    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    private String mLabel = "To :  ";
    private int mPaddingLeft;

}
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but there is a big problem with this code, at least when running on Android 5.0, because the call to setPadding in onDraw causes a new call to onDraw which then calls setPadding and so on. This can be seen by adding a Log.d call in onDraw

Answer (score 10):

You could always have a `TextView` + `EditText` in a `LinearLayout` that looks like an `EditText` like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="To:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="@null" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="To:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Type your text..."
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thnx vajaprain, but i dont want the textview and edittext side by side, i want to put a label "To:" at the extreme left of inside edittext

Answer (score 0):

In android the label is known as `TextView`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="To:"
            />

            <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
```

`EditText` has no label so you need both. Thankfully `ViewGroup`s make this relatively painless for the developer. The `EditText` uses `fill_parent` attribute so is presented tight to the "To: " label.

Comment: hey john, thnx but i dont want the textview and edittext side by side, i want to put a label "To:" at the extreme left of inside edittext

Answer (score 0):

Then use this...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >



        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TO:"    
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hey i dont want the textview and edittext side by side, i want to put a label "To:" at the extreme left of inside edittext

Comment: For this you can use TextWatcher class, which has 3 methods to overrride "AfterTextChanged,BeforeTextChanged,onTextChanged"  you can concatenate "TO" in this case......But adding TextView and setting its Text as "To" is better approach

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

EditText edittext = (EditText)getViewById(R.id.edittextid); 
edittext.setText("To:") 
}
```

Then you will see the text when ever you starting the activity.

I hope it helps....

Comment: vino, i dont want the textview and edittext side by side, i want to put a label "To:" at the extreme left of inside edittext

Comment: If so you can add like this `EditText edittext = (EditText)getViewById(R.id.edittextid);` `edittext.setText("To:")` use this in `onCreate()`. Then you will see the text when ever you starting the activity.

Comment: This to: has to remain as part of the EditText, and not get deleted when the user uses a backspace

Comment: @Silverback ya i know that but his need is like that.. he wants To to display even the user clicks in edittext view...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Here FrameLayout, Within which you can use 3 widgets :

1.TextView with set Text "TO"

1. Next to TextView You can have Edittext where you can enter the Data
2. Last is ImageButton Showing Cross Sign...

Set Background image of the FrameLayout with rounded rectangle,,,,

Answer (score 0):

**Rounded Text View**

---

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_textview"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="To:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Enter your text..."
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/stop" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**rounded_textview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TO:"    
        />
```

Comment: the TO: is not supposed to be a part of the EditText. it should not get deleted by back space operation also.