# Trying to create an EditText with a Label without the label being moved

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create an EditText that has a Label **inside the EditText** and I've been using the second suggestion of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082462/label-in-a-editbox-in-android#).

I've managed to sort of get it working, but with a few problems.  Here's how it currently looks:

[image: First Screenshot]

That's fine, until you try and enter some text. Initially there is no margin between the label and the entered text:

[image: Second Screenshot]

Also, the label cannot be removed with backspace, but it does disappear when you enter enough text to push it off the left:

[image: Third Screenshot]

Here is the code for my custom EditText - almost the same as in the thread mentioned above:

```
public class KingdomSpasEditText extends EditText {

    private int paddingLeft;
    private String label = "";

    public KingdomSpasEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    }

    public KingdomSpasEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        label = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://www.kingdomspas.com/android/custom", "label");
        if (label == null) {
            label = "";
        }
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        Rect size = new Rect();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(label, 0, label.length(), size);
        setPadding(paddingLeft + size.width(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight(), getPaddingBottom());
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawText(label, paddingLeft + size.left, size.bottom + getPaddingTop() + 50, textPaint);
    }


    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }




}
```

You may notice that in the drawText() I am adding 50 to the top padding.  If I don't it looks like this:

[image: Fifth Screenshot]

This seems like a hack to me.

Here is the XML used to create each EditText - the only difference being the label.  They are both in a TableRow which is, obviously, part of a TableLayout:

```
<com.kingdomspas.android.kingdomspasforms.formfields.KingdomSpasEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" android:background="@drawable/round" 
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                kingdomspas:label="Test Text 1: ">

                <requestFocus />
            </com.kingdomspas.android.kingdomspasforms.formfields.KingdomSpasEditText>
```

OK, thanks for sticking with me.  Here is a summary of my problems:

1) How can I create a margin between the label and the entered text?
2) How can I prevent the label disapearing of to the right?
3) Is there a better way of   my label in the Edittext

Comment: It would probably be much easier to use the first suggestion of the accepted answer: Use a LinearLayout with a TextView and an EditText.

Comment: I tried that and it's not as good.  Plus, I'm going to need lots of these, so some sort of re-use seems sensible.