# Edit text with Text Left side

Tags: android

I need to have a decimal number in an `EditText` and some text to the left of it.

This is what I need my result to look like:

[image]

How could I make this?

Comment: Put a TextView close to an EditText.

Comment: Relative layout and alignments. What have you tried?

Comment: I want to avoid relative layout for this.

Comment: I took relative with background(as shown in pic). Text View align to left and Edit text  Align to right .But no effcet.

Comment: Check this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082462/label-in-a-editbox-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Its nos the same style but is a good example  for what you need

```
<FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/mobile"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:background="@drawable/some_edittext_background"
            android:labelFor="@+id/editText"
            android:maxLength="9"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="48dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/prefix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:text="+971" />
</FrameLayout>
```